# Reading data from "Export to excel" URL into R

Tags: php, r, excel, web-scraping

I am viewing consensus fantasy football projection data for individual players at this URL:

[Sub-optimal projection data format](http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php?max-yes=true&min-yes=true)

However, in the top right corner there is an "Export" link to the same data in a cleaner format. This link prompts the user to save the data to an .xls file. This is the data that I would like to read into R. I am not sure whether I would be able to read it in directly from the URL, or have R save it to an excel file and then read it in. I have no preference, as long as I do not have to manually save each excel file, as I plan on doing this frequently.

My question is, how can I create an automated process in R where I enter the export to excel URL and then read that data into R?

[Preferred projection data format](http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php?export=xls&week=4&min-yes=true&max-yes=true) (this a prompt to save to .xls)

```
library("gdata")
qb_url <- "http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php?export=xls&week=4&min-yes=true&max-yes=true"
download.file(qb_url, "qb.xls")
```

I am now trying a read.table function and skipping the first 5-6 rows, however, since the first column is full names, sometimes with suffices, it is splitting the names into three separate columns, while I want them in just one character column. I've tried StringsAsFactors = FALSE and other pieces of code, but to no avail. I am reading through the read.table documentation websites, but I am not able to see what I am doing wrong/missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `rvest`. Those pages have a tag for the download:

```
<a id="export-xls" href="?export=xls&amp;week=4&amp;min-yes=true&amp;max-yes=true" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export</a>
```

You can grab that with:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php?max-yes=true&min-yes=true"
pg <- read_html(URL)

html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a#export-xls"), "href")
```

Which produces:

```
## [1] "?export=xls&week=4&min-yes=true&max-yes=true"
```

Just append it to the domain+query:

```
http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php
```

and download it in any one of at least 5 ways in R code. Here's a `download.file()` example:

```
dl_query <- html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a#export-xls"), "href")

download.file(sprintf("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php%s", dl_query),
          "filenametosaveitas.csv")
```

I used "`.csv`" since it's not really an Excel file. But, it's a fugly CSV so you'll have to massage it a bit first with `read.table`:

```
dat <- read.table("filenametosaveitas.csv", skip=4, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

And then voilá, you have your data:

```
dplyr::glimpse(dat)

## Observations: 90
## Variables: 33
## $ Player.Name    (fctr) Aaron Rodgers, Cam Newton, Russell Wilson, Andrew Luck, Carson Palmer, P...
## $ Team           (fctr) GB, CAR, SEA, IND, ARI, DEN, ATL, BUF, NO, OAK, CIN, BAL, SD, SF, PHI, N...
## $ pass_att       (dbl) 34.7, 32.1, 29.6, 34.1, 35.6, 38.8, 37.9, 32.2, 38.8, 38.2, 34.6, 37.8, 3...
## $ pass_att.High  (dbl) 39.6, 33.0, 33.8, 39.0, 38.0, 45.5, 41.2, 36.3, 43.6, 39.5, 40.0, 43.0, 3...
## $ pass_att.Low   (dbl) 32.0, 31.4, 27.0, 22.1, 32.2, 35.0, 35.0, 27.2, 35.0, 37.0, 31.0, 35.0, 3...
## $ pass_cmp       (dbl) 22.8, 20.0, 18.3, 21.2, 23.3, 25.4, 24.4, 19.8, 25.4, 23.7, 21.2, 23.5, 2...
## $ pass_cmp.High  (dbl) 25.3, 21.9, 19.3, 24.0, 26.6, 28.2, 25.8, 22.4, 29.2, 26.3, 25.0, 27.0, 2...
## $ pass_cmp.Low   (dbl) 21.0, 19.1, 17.0, 13.2, 21.4, 23.0, 23.0, 18.3, 23.0, 22.0, 18.4, 21.9, 2...
## $ pass_yds       (dbl) 283.2, 240.2, 228.5, 254.6, 279.5, 295.9, 282.8, 232.7, 290.4, 265.8, 245...
## $ pass_yds.High  (dbl) 317.7, 251.0, 235.2, 298.0, 330.0, 325.5, 306.0, 266.3, 324.1, 275.0, 275...
## $ pass_yds.Low   (dbl) 262.0, 231.0, 220.0, 153.9, 258.0, 273.0, 270.0, 208.4, 260.0, 249.7, 227...
## $ pass_tds       (dbl) 2.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.9, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.7, 1.9, 1.1, 1.7...
## $ pass_tds.High  (dbl) 3.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.4, 2.1, 2.4, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.2, 2.0...
## $ pass_tds.Low   (dbl) 1.9, 1.3, 1.0, 1.0, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.8, 1.0, 1.4...
## $ pass_ints      (dbl) 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8...
## $ pass_ints.High (dbl) 0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.6, 1.2, 1.0...
## $ pass_ints.Low  (dbl) 0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6...
## $ rush_att       (dbl) 3.8, 7.8, 7.4, 3.9, 1.9, 1.2, 1.9, 5.2, 1.4, 2.3, 3.5, 2.3, 1.3, 6.9, 1.9...
## $ rush_att.High  (dbl) 5.0, 8.5, 9.0, 5.5, 3.1, 1.7, 2.5, 6.0, 2.8, 3.0, 4.2, 3.7, 2.0, 9.0, 2.4...
## $ rush_att.Low   (dbl) 3.0, 7.0, 6.4, 1.5, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.5, 0.0, 1.7, 3.0, 1.5, 0.0, 6.1, 1.0...
## $ rush_yds       (dbl) 19.4, 41.6, 38.4, 16.9, 5.5, 0.1, 6.8, 26.6, 3.8, 7.5, 11.9, 6.9, 3.1, 40...
## $ rush_yds.High  (dbl) 24.0, 46.8, 40.8, 23.0, 14.3, 2.3, 8.8, 35.1, 10.4, 10.0, 18.3, 16.9, 4.7...
## $ rush_yds.Low   (dbl) 17.3, 39.2, 33.8, 6.2, 2.6, -1.0, 5.0, 14.3, 0.0, 6.0, 8.0, 3.0, 0.0, 35....
## $ rush_tds       (dbl) 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0...
## $ rush_tds.High  (dbl) 0.1, 0.6, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1...
## $ rush_tds.Low   (dbl) 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
## $ fumbles        (dbl) 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3...
## $ fumbles.High   (dbl) 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3...
## $ fumbles.Low    (dbl) 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2...
## $ fpts           (dbl) 22.1, 19.8, 19.8, 18.4, 17.9, 17.9, 17.3, 17.1, 17.1, 16.7, 16.6, 16.4, 1...
## $ fpts.High      (dbl) 28.8, 24.0, 25.8, 24.0, 22.0, 22.5, 22.0, 22.8, 22.0, 22.8, 22.8, 22.3, 2...
## $ fpts.Low       (dbl) 19.5, 16.9, 17.7, 9.8, 16.1, 16.8, 16.8, 14.8, 15.2, 13.7, 13.7, 14.5, 15...
## $ X              (lgl) NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
```

lather / rinse / repeat for your URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry if it came off that way, but I'm not looking for a code-writing service, I am just new and trying to learn. I have updated my original post to show my code.

Comment: hopefully the edited answer provides some further guidance/assistance. (argh…i prbly shld have added `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `read.table`)

Comment: This is fantastic. I'm interested to see what is producing the variable "X". Anyways, I'm going to take some time and desconstruct this to see what you did. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have a question. I've repeated this step for my other URLs, and I am encountering a slight issue for other positions. For certain players with apostrophes in their name, such as running back De'Anthony Thomas of KC, all of their statistics are contained in the Name variable, and statistics of another player, in this case Ka'Deem Carey of CHI, are filled in the other variables of that row. Is this issue likely related to the apostrophes in the name? I tried the gsub() function, replacing some or all apostrophes in pg with "", but that threw my html_attr() function off. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to follow up with my comment, I am going to try the gsub() function on the .csv file. Not sure why I didn't think of it earlier; part of the learning curve. Will update if its successful.

Comment: Change of plans. Through the site, I found another suggestion to use `quote = "\""` in my read.table() function. It appears like this worked like a charm. Thank you.